# How do I pass specific optional arguments?

Tags: php, class, constructor, optional-arguments

I have 2 cases.

- Case 1: pass the `name` and `age`.
- Case 2: pass `name` and `gender`.

How can I do this?

---

```
class User {

    function __construct($name=NULL, $gender=NULL, $age=NULL) {
        ...
    }

}

// How do I pass specific arguments here?
$case_1 = new User("Bob", 34);
$case_2 = new User("James", "m");
```

Comment: `new User("Bob", null, 34);`

Comment: @miken32 I know I can pass null into the parameter I don't want anything in. However, if I don't know how the internal structure of the object is made, how would  I know `NULL` is the default parameter? In python you can do `User(age=34)`

Comment: @miken32 Oh I see, thanks!

Comment: Actually, I take that back, I was thinking of something else. :) The null value will get passed to the function. The posted answer is your best bet.

Comment: Related: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have optional arguments in PHP, but you cannot have either/or arguments as that would require function overloading which is not supported in PHP.  Given your example, you must call the constructor as follows:

```
// How do I pass specific arguments here?
$case_1 = new User("Bob", null, 34);
$case_2 = new User("James", "m");
```

If you want to eliminate the optional but required to be null argument, you will need to get clever.

Option One: Use a factory.  This would require a common argument constructor in conjunction with mutator methods for each of the unique arguments.

```
class UserFactory {
   public static function createWithGender($name, $gender)
   {
       $user = new User($name);
       $user->setGender($gender);

       return $user;
   }

   public static function createWithAge($name, $age)
   {
       $user = new User($name);
       $user->setAge($age);

       return $user;
   }
}

$case_1 = UserFactory::createWithAge("Bob", 34);
$case_2 = UserFactory::createWithGender("James", "m");
```

The factory doesn't need to be a separate class, you can alternatively add the static initializers to the User class if desired.

```
class User {
   function __construct($name = null)
   {
        ...
   }

   public static function createWithGender($name, $gender)
   {
       $user = new static($name);
       $user->setGender($gender);

       return $user;
   }

   public static function createWithAge($name, $age)
   {
       $user = new static($name);
       $user->setAge($age);

       return $user;
   }
}

$case_1 = User::createWithAge("Bob", 34);
$case_2 = User::createWithGender("James", "m");
```

Option Two: Do some argument detection.  This will only work if the arguments are all unique types.

```
class User {
    public function __construct($name, $second = null) {
        if (is_int($second)) {
            $this->age = $second;
        } else {
            $this->gender = $second;
        }
    }
}

$case_1 = new User("Bob", 34);
$case_2 = new User("James", "m");
```

Comment: Those static factory functions should probably return the user :) Also `new self(...)` (or `new static(...)` if you want to instanciate potential subclasses) would be a tad more elegant, but I'm nitpicking.

Comment: Thanks, I was a little hasty coding up the sample.  Updated with forgotten return and new static(...) for late static binding of the User object via the static initializers.